# NoReverseMatch at /edit_record/1/

Tags: python, html, django

Решил изучить создание сайтов по одному учебнику и во время выполнения одного упражнения возникла такая проблема. При открытии страницы выдаёт это:

```
NoReverseMatch at /edit_record/1/
Reverse for 'edit_record' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit_record/(?P<record_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/edit_record/1/
Django Version: 4.2.4
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'edit_record' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit_record/(?P<record_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']
Exception Location: C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\blog\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 828, in _reverse_with_prefix
Raised during:  my_blog.views.edit_record
Python Executable:  C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\blog\python.exe
Python Version: 3.11.4
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\blog_project',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\.conda\\envs\\blog\\python311.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\.conda\\envs\\blog\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\.conda\\envs\\blog\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\.conda\\envs\\blog',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\.conda\\envs\\blog\\Lib\\site-packages']

Reverse for 'edit_record' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit_record/(?P<record_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']
```

`url.py`:

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'my_blog'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.value, name='value'),
    path('records/', views.records, name='records'),
    path('edit_record/<int:record_id>/', views.edit_record, name='edit_record'),
    path('create_record/', views.create_record, name='create_record')
]
```

`edit_record.html`:

```html
{% extends "my_blog/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <p>Edit record:</p>

  <form action="{% url 'my_blog:edit_record' record.id %}" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button name="submit">save changes</button>
  </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

`views.py`:

```py
def edit_record(request, record_id):
    """Редактирует существующую запись."""
    blog_post = Blog_place.objects.get(id=record_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # Исходный запрос; форма заполняется данными текущей записи.
        form = Blog_placeForm(instance=blog_post)
    else:
        # Отправка данных POST; обработать данные.
        form = Blog_placeForm(instance=blog_post, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('my_blog:records', record_id=record.id)
        
    context = {'blog_post': blog_post, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'my_blog/edit_record.html', context)
```

Comment: `record_id=record.id)` — что такое `record`? В показанном вами коде такой переменной не существует

Comment: А, ну так в шаблоне то же самое: `{% url 'my_blog:edit_record' record.id %}` — что такое `record`? Вы не передаёте в шаблон переменную с таким названием

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты пытаешься сформировать `url 'my_blog:edit_record' record.id`, но сам record не передаёшь в контекст. Насколько я понял, в твоём приложении record это то же самое, что и blog_post, поэтому в шаблоне замени
`url 'my_blog:edit_record' record.id`
На
`url 'my_blog:edit_record' blog_post.id`

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало.